# How to work many users in the same feature in GitHub?

Tags: github

We are 3 developers working in the same feature in GitHub.

There is a master.
Each of the developers has their own fork of the master.

Now each developer added the remote fork of the other 2 developers. And with communication we are pulling the changes of the other 2 developers and then merging and pushing to the developer fork. So the others developers can pull and merge to push again to their fork.

The problem with this approach is that we have more merging to do, that if we were all pushing and pulling to the same branch. And the communication is a must.

We try to make a fork of a fork and we couldn't. Github does not support it.
We try to push to the same branch, we couldn't. It seems that also Github does not support it.

So there is a way in Github we all push and pull to the same branch or repository? And when we finish we do a pull request to a master?

Any recommendation about how to work many developers in the same feature in Github?

Comment: As you are just three developers you could use rebase. Anyway, can you explain what to work in same feature means? I mean in terms of files and directories.

Comment: @juanpastas in terms of files and directories we work many times in the same directory and in the same files. And what do you mean we can use rebase?

Comment: I have heard that when there are not a lot of developers rebase flow is good, but I have not experienced to be modifying same files at same time. Anyway, I think modifying same files at same time should be similar in resolving conflicts step. Do you know how to use rebase? I ask because I am not sure about what your question mean?

Comment: @juanpastas I use a rebase like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge . We use it before pulling request to the master

Comment: Hmmm, sorry I have not experienced what you say in your question. Maybe you can find a way to not to modify same files. I suppose that you problem is you edit not only same files, besides same lines, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of forking and pulling, you can use the other collaboration mode prevalent in GitHub: shared repositories. Shared repositories are useful for small, private development groups.

Give your developers push access to a central repository and they will be able to collaborate without pull requests and excessive merging. (Pull requests are still useful if you decide to use the shared repository model especially for code review and feature discussions.)

In GitHub terminology, a person able to push/pull from a repository is a *collaborator*. Collaborators are set in the repository settings page.

Answer (score 2):

> So there is a way in Github we all push and pull to the same branch or repository? And when we finish we do a pull request to a master?

Start an [organization](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations), move your repo there, and give all developers push access.